# Клик за пределы области

Tags: jquery

При нажатии на **#test**, оно открывается. Как сделать, если кликнул за пределы **#test**, оно закрывалось?

```
<body>
  <div id="test" style="display: none; background: #ccc; width: 300px;">
   тут что-то
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#test').click(function() {
    $(this).show();
   });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Сейчас #test — display: none, так что кликнуть по нему не возможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/qvNsS/ — если я правильно вас понял:

```
$(document)
    .on('click', function (evt){
        if( !evt.isDefaultPrevented() ){
            $('#test .hidden').hide();
        }
    })
    .on('click', '#test', function (evt){
        $('.hidden', this).show();
        evt.preventDefault();
    })
;
```

Comment: @RubaXa, большое спасибо! Помогли очень сильно ^.^

Answer (score 1):

[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) в JQuery как раз для подобных случаев.

Answer (score 0):

по другому элементу кликайте:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#test').show();
   });
```

Comment: @Maris, документ это же всё, получается даже если я нажму в области #test, то она закроется.

Comment: @ModaL, есть такая штука — e.stopPropagation(); — вот ее запилите внутрь вашего $('#test').click(), ну и погуглите, что это такое.